# Rails - query a has_many association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I'm having trouble querying a has_many association. The context is stores.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: store
end
```

**Stores table:**

```
id  name
1   Macys
2   Target
3   Dillards
```

**Items table:**

```
id  store_id    name
1   1           pants
2   1           shirt
3   2           pants
4   2           shirt
5   3           shirt
```

I'm trying to query for stores that only sell shirts. So I need a query that returns the `store` record with `id` of `3`.

When I tried to do

```
Store.includes(:items).where(
  items: { name: %w(shirts)} ).references(:items)
```

it returns `store_ids` 1, 2, and 3 (all stores) because they all have shirts.

Comment: Please provide the expected result of your query because the question is not clear.

Comment: The expected result is the store record with ID 3 (Dillards) because that's the only store that sells just shirts.


`#<Store id: 3, name: "Dillards">`

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using:

```
Store.joins(:items).group('items.store_id').having("max(items.name) = 
  min(items.name) and min(items.name) = 'shirt'")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Store.includes(:items)
  .where(items: { name: 'shirt' })
  .where.not(id:
    Item.where.not(name: 'shirt').select(:store_id)
  )
```

*Hopefully there's a better way... (if anyone)*

Answer (score 1):

In your `Item` model, you need to set the `counter_cache`:

```
belongs_to :store, counter_cache: true
```

then your query will be:

```
Store.joins(:items).where('items_count = ? AND items.name = ?', 1, 'shirt')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this as mentioned in the post that stores only having items as shirts would be:

```
Store.joins(:item).where("items.name = ?", 'shirt').where.not(item_name: Item.where("items.name != ?", "shirt"))
```

Hope it helps!!